# What is definition of height of a binary tree?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

In definition of the height of the tree I have wrote "Height: The height of any node is the longest path from the node to any leaf (The height of
any leaf is 0 )"

and my teacher wrote for me "This is strongly connected with directed edges in the tree under consideration. It is better to note it in the text. (Otherwise, if the leaf will be in another branch then the path can exceed depth of the tree.)"

can someone explain my mistake ?

Comment: The teacher is saying that, with your definition,  the path could go from the node up to the root and then down to a leaf on another branch, giving a height greater than the height of the root.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

What your teacher wrote means that for your definition to be intuitive one has to assume that the edges in your tree are directed from the root towards the leaves. Consider the following tree with undirected edges: $V = \{a, b, c, d \} E = \{\{a, b\}, \{b, c\}, \{c, d\} \}$ where $b$ is the root. You would want the height function to do the following: $h(a) = 0, h(b) = 2, h(c) = 1, h(d) = 0$. But according to your definition (if we are in the undirected setting) you get $h(c) = 2$ because the longest path from $c$ to a leaf is $c, b, a$.

When we only consider trees where the edges are directed away from the root (in the example this would mean $E = \{ (b, a), (b, c), (c, d)\}$) then your definition works.

Comment: Thank you, so if I write like The height of a binary tree is the largest number of edges in a path from the root node to a leaf node (The height of any leaf is 0 ). Now the problem is solved then?

Comment: Well in your question you seem to define the height of a node in a binary tree. Here you only define the height of the tree itself i.e. the height of the root. If you only need the height of the root (which is the same as the height of the tree) then your definition in the comment above is correct, yes.